# Where to get information on built-in NSS services?

Tags: nsswitch

Where can I get detailed information (including file format, database format) on built-in NSS services such as db, files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the source!

Prepare via:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-src
```

Then, pick a file associated with NSS, and find out which software package(s) provide it. Let's use `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
dpkg -S /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Then, select a package, and `apt-src install` it.